# How to display realtime chart on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, highcharts, real-time

I've been working on this for some days now but I can't seem to find the answer. I have a webpage which displays a question and answers to choose from and when you click submit it goes to the next question. The problem is trying to display the results after each question as a bar chart on a webpage. I'm trying to make the server push one question first and when an answer is picked, the chart is updated in realtime. I've gone through so many socket with php tutorials but I'm still finding it hard. I'm using Composer to work with client and server. I tried and tested out sending messages from the server to a client webpage which worked but that didn't really help as I'm trying to update with client input.

The testing code below counts and displays the number of votes after a question. The data doesn't enter the database at the moment as I've been trying to do that and it's not entering.

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_GET['question'])){
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'quiz');
$question = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['question']);
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
                $answer = $row2['answer'];
                $correct = $row2['correct'];
                $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'" onclick="getVote(this.value)" >'.$answer.'</label>                 
                ';

                        }   
            }
$vote = isset($_GET['rads']);
                //get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}
//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table> 
<?php if(isset($_GET['question'])){?>
<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()">Submit</button></span><?php }?>
<?php
```

If the chart is displayed from the database, it's not updating realtime. I want the chart updated after user input. Any ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: First I think you should try to put some static number and update it in real time - have you achieved that? If yes, then later make sure you are using number, not a string, to update chart's values. There is full API for it [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) (one point) and [series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) (multiple points).

Comment: Oh, thanks. That clarified a lot of things. Also, do you have any idea how I can input the values poll straight to the database. I have `mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO stats (question_id,correct,wrong) VALUES ('$question,$yes,$no')" or die(mysql_error()));` but nothing gets into the database. I think it may have something to do with incrementing _+1_ I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not PHP guy ;) But remember, that PHP is executed only once (when you load page).